# Why is my rails application not capture my stripe error? am I using rescue correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, stripe-payments

I'm testing out my stripe payment page but when I put in the wrong details the error is not captured and instead I am redirected to website.co.uk/subscriptions.

What is going on here? Am I using rescue corrently? I've tried both *Rescue Stripe::CardError* and normal *rescue* but the errors do not seem to be captured....

If anyone could lend a hand and tell me what is going on I would be very grateful.

```
  def create

    @account = User.find_by_id(params[:account_id])
    key = @account.access_code
    Stripe.api_key = key
    account_suid = @account.uid
    @order = Order.find(params[:order])
    charge = @order.amount * 100
    fee = @order.amount * 1
  
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: @order.email, source: token)
 
    begin

     Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
       customer: customer,
       amount: (charge).to_i, 
       confirm: true,
       currency: 'gbp',
       payment_method_types: ['card'],
       application_fee_amount: (fee).to_i,
     }, {
       stripe_account: account_suid
     })
    options = {
      stripe_id: customer.id
    }

    options.merge!(
      card_last4: params[:user][:card_last4],
      card_exp_month: params[:user][:card_exp_month],
      card_exp_year: params[:user][:card_exp_year],
      card_type: params[:user][:card_brand]
    )

    OrderFiniJob.perform_now(@order)
    OrderMailer.recived(@order).deliver_now
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to), notice: "Your order has been successful "

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      format.html { redirect_to new_subscription_path(:account_id => @account, :amount => @order.amount, :order => @order), notice: "There has been an error with your payment. Please try again. Errorcode: 1" }
  
    rescue => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      format.html { redirect_to new_subscription_path(:account_id => @account, :amount => @order.amount, :order => @order), notice: "There has been an issue. Errorcode: 222" }

    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      # handle not found error
      format.html { redirect_to new_subscription_path(:account_id => @account, :amount => @order.amount, :order => @order), notice: "There has been an issue. Errorcode: 333" }
    rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
      # handle other ActiveRecord errors
      format.html { redirect_to new_subscription_path(:account_id => @account, :amount => @order.amount, :order => @order), notice: "There has been an issue. Errorcode: 444" }
    rescue # StandardError
    format.html { redirect_to new_subscription_path(:account_id => @account, :amount => @order.amount, :order => @order), notice: "There has been an issue. Errorcode: 555" }
    rescue Exception
      format.html { redirect_to new_subscription_path(:account_id => @account, :amount => @order.amount, :order => @order), notice: "There has been an issue. Errorcode: 666" }
    end

  end
```

Comment: In stripe if you just enter any details then I am not sure which error is thrown. But if you want to test some specific error then you need to use these particular cards provided [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses)

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the right controller? I can't see an obvious reason why you would get redirected to that url. Can you post the relevant entries from your log file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you add some logging to each `rescue` so you can see in your logs which one is hit, and see if that helps.